# How to execute SPARQL Select query using EasyRdf locally in PHP?

Tags: php, sparql, rdf, virtuoso, easyrdf

I have JSON-LD data on URL http://mystore.com/data1 . I want to execute SPARQL SELECT query in PHP.
Here is my code :

```
$sparql = new EasyRdf_Sparql_Client('http://mystore.com/data1');
$result = $sparql->query(
    'SELECT *
        WHERE {
          ?operation <http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#template> ?templateValue.
        }'
);
print_r($result);
```

Above code showing all JSON-LD triples instead of filtered data based on query.
After reading docs , I have doubt . 
**In above code params in EasyRdf_Sparql_Client should be Sparql Endpoint while I am sending data URL**. Am I doing correct ? I think Sparql Endpoint is SPARQL query engine which I deduce after referring this standard [example](https://github.com/njh/easyrdf/blob/0.9.0/examples/basic_sparql.php) , it have dbpedia url which is Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor. **I want run SPARQL SELECT on my local/remote JSON-LD data. How to do that in php?**

Comment: indeed you have to use the SPARQL service

Comment: @AKSW  How to do that in php ?

Comment: I don't know whether EasyRDF supports an in-memory SPARQL endpoint.